# how to fix offline data from local sqlite shows incorrect design though it is working online?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

[Online screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV1hw.jpg) [Offline screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGXdq.jpg) Below is a code written for displaying offline data from sqlite. Same code is written in online as well.

This code is written in oncreate() method.

```
        Cursor c = db2.getData(scode);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
               .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);        
       ArrayList<String> mArrayList = null;
        String Surveyques = "";
        String rd_opt1 = "";
        String rd_opt2 = "";
        String rd_opt3 = "";
        String rd_opt4 = "";
        Log.i(TAG, "final cursor count size: " + c.getCount());
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
                mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                Surveyques = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Ques"));
                rd_opt1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qst_Opt_A"));
                rd_opt2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qst_Opt_B"));
                rd_opt3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qst_Opt_C"));
                rd_opt4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Qst_Opt_D"));

                mArrayList.add(Surveyques);
                mArrayList.add(rd_opt1);
                mArrayList.add(rd_opt2);
                mArrayList.add(rd_opt3);
                mArrayList.add(rd_opt4);
            offlinedataArr.add(mArrayList);


            }

        for(int j = 0; j < offlinedataArr.size(); j++)
        {

            ArrayList<String> tempArray = (ArrayList<String>) offlinedataArr.get(j);

            TextView tv_ques = new TextView(this);
            RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
            RadioButton rdBtn = new RadioButton(this);
            tv_ques.setText(tempArray.get(0));
            rdBtn.setText(tempArray.get(1));
            rdBtn.setText(tempArray.get(2));
            rdBtn.setText(tempArray.get(3));
            rg.addView(rdBtn);
            viewGroup.addView(tv_ques);
            viewGroup.addView(rg);
            tv_ques.setX(50);
            tv_ques.setY(500*j);
            rg.setY(500 * j);
        }
```

Already tried : 
X and Y axis co-ordinate setup

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: unable to fetch  correct design only from offline data.

Comment: Please add everything relevant to the question, especially your question. And what does that **exactly** mean? What is "offline data"?

Comment: I've uploaded screenshots. Kindly go through with it.

Comment: What is the difference between online and offline? Why is the data not loadable? Can you debug that problem first on your own?

Comment: by online i mean My phone is connected to internet, so in this case i can see all the questions  & its options.
But when my phone is disconnected from internet at that time the layout changes and my questions overlap on my options... and it shows uneven layout.

Comment: And why does this happen? Can you debug that?